# How To Replacing/Emulating Microsoft SQL Server on Linux?

Tags: linux, sql

I'd like to use a database-enabled version of a particular application (http://idimager.com), but it requires Microsoft SQL Server.  My home ecosystem is powered by a Gentoo Linux server, and I'm curious what my options are.

The ones I can think of are:

- Get another box running Windows (Yuck - nothing against Windows, but I don't need two full time servers)
- Switch my Linux box to Windows (I do love my Gentoo tho, so I'd rather not)
- Run SQL Server under Wine (I'm scared that'll be slow, however...?)

Are there any other options?

Comment: Running a Virtual machine would be a good option in your case, I think.

Comment: sql server will not run under Wine

Answer (score 1):

IDimager is already a Windows application.  Why not just run the DB on the same system as the application?

Also, the application seems to support using SQLite as well as MS SQL Server.  Why not use that?

Comment: I don't leave my PC on all the time, and I have multiple PC's I want to access it from.  Using SQLite won't solve my problem as the database isn't central.

Comment: The SQLite DB can be stored on your server, but SQLite is generally not geared towards *concurrent* writers.  As long as you don't have multiple people trying to modify the DB (import, tag, or organize images) at the same time, it should be safe.  If you can live with that particular constraint, you should be able to use SQLite.